# Bootstrap table tbody scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize my bootstrap table. If the table height is larger than a certain height I want the `<tbody>` to scroll without scrolling the rest of the table. I have tried pretty much everything I can think of but the table wont even change sizes.

Does anyone know what classes I need to modify to fix this? Here's the elements I use in my table:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="col-xs-1"/>
        <col class="col-xs-1"/>
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

And [here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TkyE/).

Comment: Just using CSS you'd need a height on the tbody element along with overflow on it. Otherwise there are many JavaScript/jQuery solutions out there.

Comment: I've done exactly that in the jsFiddle, doesn't do anything. I think there's some bootstrap code I have to disable.

Comment: If you don't mind rolling your own CSS, here is a tutorial on how to implement it. Best of all it's IE6 compliant. :) http://tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody/

Comment: @user2708395 That solution seems to work's but messes up the responsive width of the table and columns. :/ Was hoping I was doing something wrong but according to that article this is just tables working as intented. Overflowing the tbody without affecting the rest isn't possible by default.

Comment: @hustlerinc I think you are correct. In the past I have also had trouble building scrollable tbody's. It seems like something that might not be possible without some kind of hack. I'll keep watch on this question as I'd like to find a good solution as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Horizontal Scrollable Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560208/bootstrap-horizontal-scrollable-table)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with Bootstrap 2.3.2. I had to modify my table some, but a pretty good website I found with a complete css solution is here: 
http://www.cssbakery.com/2010/12/css-scrolling-tables-with-fixed.html

I basically took the scrollableArea and scrollableContainer css parts on this site, changed a couple class names to match with what I already had, and used this instead of bootstrap. Maybe this can help, maybe not, but definitely a good alternative.